# How to structure a nested "x if condition else y" so Black will leave it legible?

Tags: python, python-black

For a double nested `x if condition else y` it was legible before `black` got into the fray. It loses the nice indentations I had placed and now it's just a *Wall of Code*:

```
        clause = (
            (f"{self.colname} " if self.colname else "") + self.sql
            if self.sql
            else self.values_filter()
            if self.values is not None
            and len(self.values) > 0
            and (self.colname is not None)
            else self.range_filter()
            if self.range is not None and (self.colname is not None)
            else None
        )
```

I'm going to break this into separate pieces for expediency but for legacy purposes would like to know if there's some way to get a legible format for this language construct.

Comment: Try adding parentheses, maybe it will indent them nicely.

Comment: actually yea, I did add parens to another similar case and that did help. Looking more closely the parens in the above sql are for nested pieces not the main flow

Comment: `black` is the wrong tool to use if you care about *what* formatting is used, rather than just having *consistent* formatting.

Comment: @chepner  Maybe so but it's in use in the company projects and that's a fact.  So I'm wondering whether I need to dump this language construct

Comment: I would. Personally, I find this example too long to be particularly readable, at least split into so many short, equally indented lines.

Comment: @chepner  You might have missed the point: _black_ removes the formatting / indentation that had already been in place.  I come from _scala_ and fp background so this construct is used _all the time_ .  It just does not work well in python it seems and even less so when  _black_ gets into the fray.  I went to a traditional assignment block instead though it is another pain point to be unnecessarily verbose that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a pair of `# fmt` directives around code you don't want Black to reformat:

```py
# fmt: off
... your carefully formatted construct here ...
# fmt: on
```